# What does "work away" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, hiberno-english

What does "work away" in the fourth paragraph mean? At first I thought it meant "be away from home for work", but it also seems to mean "to put forth a persistent, diligent, and devoted effort (toward some task or activity)" [(source)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+away).

[Here's the full article](https://www.un.org/dgacm/sites/www.un.org.dgacm/files/documents_St_Jerome/16th_St_Jerome/eglish_translation_piece_-_dishwasher.pdf) for reference; the relevant paragraph is quoted below:

> **There are those who know how to fill a dishwasher, and those who don’t care***
>
> [...]
>
> A recent survey carried out in Britain revealed that couples quarrel about household chores about five times a week. Only five times? I can only presume their partners **work away** a lot. Himself absolutely pulls his weight when he’s here. Let there be no doubt of that. We just have different ways of doing things and we see things differently. For example, he sees the end of the banisters as a perfectly acceptable place to hang his coat, whereas I think the brand new coat rack that I assembled and placed under the staircase specifically for this purpose, the one adorned with everyone else’s coat, is where they should go.

Comment: I think your original guess was right.

Comment: So one of them work a lot and without pause outside the house and that's why they quarrel about the chores maybe . I think in this passage it means working all day , Like you said .

Comment: I agree that your original assumption was correct. The idiom you've linked is "work away (at something)." One might say they are working away at a project, or working away at a problem, but without the "at" here, it just means to work away, i.e., out of the home.

Comment: *"Only five times?"* [that's not many if their partner is around all the time].

Comment: It would be interesting to convert this question into a more general question about the current use of that phrase in this sense. Traditionally having a job always involved spending the working hours away from home, so there was generally no need for it. I suspect that it is because of the prevalence of working from home during the COVID era, that the need  arose for making it clear that one is speaking about working away from home in such cases.

Comment: Hello, Alex. Only 'have jobs that often take them away from home' is a natural reading here. '... when he's here' in the next sentence surely forces this. And the suggested alternative reading ('I can only presume the partners of those canvassed work their socks off') doesn't explain the surprisingly low frequency of quarrels, just restates it.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I think it's clear now.

Comment: I think it's referring to people who're away in the evenings/overnight as well as during the day, from the context - you'd normally argue about housework if you were both home in the evening, so if you don't the article assumes it's because you're not there at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence you have given, it means 'work away from home'. For example, John is working away, on 'an oil rig in the middle of the North Sea'.

She is saying 'the only reason they don't argue about housework, is because he isn't there!' - because he is away, not in the home. Meaning, if he was there, they'd argue 'five times a week'. But he's not, so they don't.

There is another meaning to 'work away', or 'working away' on or at something, which means 'to focus on a task ' or 'to get on with a task'

So,

John is working away on an oil rig' can mean 'he is busy, working on his tasks, over there. Note how I removed the comma, to make this somewhat clearer. Though it is still ambiguous.

Here are some more examples of 'working away' that mean 'getting on with the task':

- Emily is working away on her embroidery, and has nearly completed the handkerchief she is embellishing.
- John is working away on his thesis and hopes to have it finished by Christmas.
- Susan is working away at her job, and soon hopes to be promoted to manager.

Note that some of these, such as 'Susan' above are ambiguous, this example could for example mean that Susan is working in Sunderland whereas she normally lives in London. Or, it could mean that she is working hard at her tasks. You'd have to ask to find out which one was correct.

Just for clarity, in the light of some comments, 'work away' does not usually mean 'work outside of the house'! It means 'work in a different town', at least, and usually, requiring that you stay somewhere else for a period of time. More commonly, it means you work in a far away location, like a North Sea oil rig, or in Greece for the Summer, on a cruise ship for 3 months, or anywhere that requires you to stay away from home, and work for a period of time requiring at least one, but usually more, nights stay away from your home.

Answer (score -1):

The source for this article is *The Irish Times.*  [As this thread on WordReference explains,](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/work-away.959065/) "work away" has a different meaning in Irish English:

> 'Work away' is very much an IE expression; an informal way of saying "carry on" or "go ahead."

I'm not quite sure if it makes sense in this context; "carry on" doesn't fit well here either. But I do suspect that this phrase would be interpreted differently by speakers from Ireland than by speakers of other dialects.